# Copy data from azure blob storage to adls gen 2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have around 2 million json files in azure blob storage.Each file contains one record.I need to move all those json files to adls gen 2 whose createdate is greater than 2019-01-01.

Note:createdate is one of the field inside json.

Is it possible to achieve this through azure data factory

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use query to do this. First all of please put the data into some space that can do data analytics.

First, create a **copy activity1**(copy data from azure blob storage to sql database), then create a **copy activity2**(copy data from sql database to adls gen2.)

[image]

In the source of the copy activity2, please do like this:

[image]

```
select *  
from dbo.test1 A 
where A.createdate >= '2019-01-01'
```

I have already do a test and it works fine. Please have a try.